# SerialDevice dispose method not working in certain cases, Windows 10 IOT

Tags: uwp, serial-port, windows-10-iot-core

I have developed simple UWP application to communicate via serial port. I am using **SerialDevice** class for communication. Before reading any data from serial port if I dispose SerialDevice object it's dispose methods works fine
once I start reading data via serial port and then if I want to disconnect to this device and I dispose SerialDevice object, it stuck in dispose method.
Following are my functions I am using to read, write and disconnect:

```
public class UARTCommunicationProvider
{
    SerialDevice _serialPort;
    private DataReader _serialPortReader;
    private DataWriter _serialPortWriter;
    private CancellationTokenSource _serialPortReadWriteCTS = null;
    public UARTCommunicationProvider()
    {
        _serialPortReadWriteCTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }
    public async Task<bool> ConnectAsync(string comportId)
    {
        _serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(comportId);

        if (_serialPort != null)
        {
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
            _serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            _serialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;
            _serialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
            _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            _serialPort.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;

            _serialPortReader = new DataReader(_serialPort.InputStream);
            // Set InputStreamOptions to complete the asynchronous read operation when one or more bytes is available
            _serialPortReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
            _serialPortWriter = new DataWriter(_serialPort.OutputStream);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public async void CollectData()
    {
        var command = "FL 1\n";
        while (true)
        {
            var response = await ResponseForCommandAsync(command);
            Debug.WriteLine(response)

        }
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        try
        {
            _serialPort?.Dispose(); //Stuck at this point when I try to dispose after reading few chunks of data from serial port
            _serialPortReadWriteCTS.Cancel();
            _serialPort = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> ResponseForCommandAsync(string command)
    {
        string response = string.Empty;
        if (_serialPort != null)
        {
            // Load the text from the sendText input text box to the dataWriter object
            _serialPortWriter.WriteString(command);
            UInt32 bytesWritten = await _serialPortWriter.StoreAsync();
            if (bytesWritten > 0)
            {
                bytecount = bytecount + (int)bytesWritten;
                _logger.WriteLine("Data Sent Successfully", AEIoTCommon.Common.LoggingType.Verbose);
                response = await ReadAsync();
            }
        }

        return response;
    }

    private async Task<string> ReadAsync()
    {
        string valueRead = null;
        Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;

        uint ReadBufferLength = 1024;

        try
        {
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = _serialPortReadWriteCTS.Token;

            //If task cancellation was requested, comply
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            using (var childCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(3000))
            {
                // Create a task object to wait for data on the serialPort.InputStream
                loadAsyncTask = _serialPortReader.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask(childCancellationTokenSource.Token);

                // Launch the task and wait
                UInt32 bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;
                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    //byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesRead];
                    var value = _serialPortReader.ReadString(bytesRead);

                    valueRead = value;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
        {
            Disconnect();
        }


        return valueRead;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi user224332, can you reproduce this issue using the [official serial sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/tree/develop/Samples/SerialUART/CS)?

Comment: colidyre, did you figure this out?  My app is doing the same thing on at least one version of Windows 10 (Build 16299).  It seems to work fine on Build 17763.

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with SerialDevice.Dispose() hanging up on SOME versions of Windows 10 (or it could have been related to the computer hardware).  After researching general Windows/serial port problems, it seemed likely the hang was due to a threading problem.  I was able to fix the hang by doing this in my disconnect function:

```
    public void Disconnect()
    {
        :
        // Don't call dispose directly as it hangs on some computers
        // Calling this from a separate thread prevents it from hanging...
        Thread thr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(serialPortClose));
        thr.Start();
        :
    }


    void serialPortClose()
    {
        _serialDevice.Dispose();
        _serialDevice = null;
    }
```